# Odd mysql syntax error, On and Off

Tags: php, mysql

So this is my code :

```
 $satake = $_POST['satake'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $query ="INSERT INTO `fn`('satake', 'id') VALUES ('{$satake}' , {$id} )";
    if (mysql_query($query)){
         echo 'goof';
         header("Location : home.php");
         exit;
    }         else{
        echo 'error';
        echo '</ br>';
        echo mysql_error();
    }
```

The problem is, when I run the code for the first time it gives me no error other than:

```
errorYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''satake', 'id') VALUES ('' , )' at line 1
```

but when i change a single thing and get it back to where is was , it gives me this :

```
Notice: Undefined index: satake in 

Notice: Undefined index: id in
```

I mean, my code is identical to where it was at first sight but it gives me 2 new errors when I change anything and undo my change!

Is my syntax OK or have I declared my vars badly?

Comment: You've got to enclose your column names in backticks not single quotes or omit this because you don't use reserved words: `INSERT INTO `fn`(satake, id)`

Comment: You're composing SQL code with random input from external sources. There's just no way to avoid SQL errors that way. You should read about SQL injection ASAP.

Comment: Use prepared statements (PDO, MySQLi) and you won't suffer any of those problems, nor any security issues.

Comment: yes , i mastering sql injection takes time and practice . tnx

Answer (score 1):

Try to invoke the variables only if `POST` is set and also enclose the column names inside backticks instead of quotes like:

```
if($_POST)
{
    $satake = $_POST['satake'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $query ="INSERT INTO `fn`(`satake`, `id`) VALUES ('{$satake}' , {$id} )";
                              ^
    if (mysql_query($query)){
         echo 'goof';
         header("Location : home.php");
         exit;
    }         else{
        echo 'error';
        echo '</ br>';
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}
```

Comment: i did what u said and damn NuSphere PhpED wouldnt show anything , not even an error , so ive tried it with xampp and it worked ...
thank you , but sql query of Man Programmer was right :D

Comment: can u briefly explain what if($_POST) does in this code?

Comment: @Greatone..It checks whether `$_POST` variable is set or not. ie,For eg: when we submit a form the `$_POST` array will be set with `form` element values. If the `form` is submitted `$_POST` array will be null.

Answer (score 1):

you make syntax mistake in query

```
"INSERT INTO `fn`(`satake`, `id`) VALUES ('".$satake."' , $id )";
```

correct way

Comment: yes this worked , tnx , the main problem was my IDE , NuSphere PhpED , idk why....